# How can I run a Sequel migration against Mysql with an SSL connetion

Tags: mysql, ruby, ssl, sequel

I am trying to run a migration against mysql database that require both username/password and ssl conection. How can I refer to the ca cert for the ssl connection? If I run the following command it rise an `Error: Sequel::DatabaseConnectionError: Mysql::ServerError::AccessDeniedError: Access denied`

```
sequel -m db/migrations mysql://root:password@localhost/test
```

I tried to add the sslca= params in the command line but doesn't seams to work.

UPDATE

yes sorry, here as follow you can see both the working and not working code:

1) ruby code that I use the connect to my db that works perfectly

```
connection = Sequel.mysql2(
  "db_name",
  :user => "username",
  :password => "password",
  :host => "host",
  :port => "port",
  :sslca => File.expand_path(File.join('path', 'to', 'ca.pem')),
  :max_connections => 1
)
```

2) here is the code that doesn't work, I tried to pass the `sslca` param  as --sslca= with both quoted and not but with none of those I could establish the connection

```
sequel -m db/migrations mysql://root:password@localhost/test sslca="path/to/ca.pem"
```

and the error I get back is:

```
Error: Sequel::DatabaseConnectionError: Mysql2::Error: Access denied for user 'username'@'host' (using password: YES)/path/to/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/lib/mysql2/client.rb:44:in `connect'
```

Answer (score 0):

Sequel's mysql adapter passes the following ssl parameters to the ruby-mysql library: sslkey, sslcert, sslca, sslcapath, sslcipher.  I'm not sure if just sslca is sufficient, you may need one of the other options as well.

If you aren't able to get it to work with Sequel, I would recommend trying to get it working using ruby-mysql directly.  If you can get it working with ruby-mysql but not Sequel, let me know how and I can probably get it working in Sequel as well.

Comment: I tried with both `mysql://` and `mysql2://` protocols without any success. as far as concern `sslca`, it should be fine because when I open the connection from console using Sequel.mysql2(..., :sslca => 'path/to/ca.pem') it works fine.

Comment: Can you provide the exact code you are using (just replacing the user/password parts) both for the working and not working parts.  You don't actually show how you are adding the sslca params on the command line (if you aren't quoting the connection string, you may want to try that).

Comment: Found the solution, it was just me being dumb. Here is the correct code: sequel -m db/migrations root:password@localhost/test?sslca="../mysql-ssl-ca-cert.pem" Thanks!